# Not able to play audio in google translate page

Tags: firefox, browser

I am using Firefox 34 for Ubuntu 14.04. I tried to play the audio on google translate page, not able to hear the sound. I could see an error in developer console when I press the audio button. Attached the screen shot. Even I tried with disabling other conflicting add-ons and removing ad blocker. But still the same issue. What could be missing here? Please clarify.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems some audio codec was missing. I installed gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3 plugin for Ubuntu Rhythmbox Music Player. Then I restarted firefox, and now able to hear audio on Google translate page.